# R Graphing attendance at event with join and leave times

Tags: r

I have attendance data from an online event where each row contains an email address, a join time, and a leave time. Some attendees have multiple rows since they joined, left, and then re-joined the meeting (sometimes several times). There were approximately 200 attendees over the course of the ~90 minute event. I want to create a visualization that shows when attendees joined and left over the course of the whole event. I'm thinking a graph where each attendee's join and leave times are plotted so that each attendee has a single line. I don't know where to begin and am hoping for any recommendations. Thanks! Here's a sample of what my data looks like:

```
structure(list(Email= c("email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", 
"email3@gmail.com","email3@gmail.com"), Join.Time = structure(c(as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:04:00"), 
as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:20:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:30:00"),as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:07:00"),
as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:29:00")), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),tzone = "America/New_York"), 
Leave.Time = structure(c(as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:25:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:22:00"), 
as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 14:01:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:29:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 14:33:00")), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")),.Names = c("Email", "Join.Time", "Leave.Time"), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Search for examples of plotting Gantt charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be approached by assigning a unique integer ID to each email (numbered 1:(number of participants)) and then plotting a line segment from the `Join.Time` to the `Leave.Time` at the y value of `ID`. To do this I converted the original data structure into a data frame and then merged it with another data frame of emails and IDs. You can label each y value (`ID`) with the email if you want to. The graphics will probably need finessing to suit your goals.

[image]

```
# turn initial structure into a dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(structure(list(Email= c("email1@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", "email2@gmail.com", 
                        "email3@gmail.com","email3@gmail.com"), Join.Time = structure(c(as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:04:00"), 
                                                                                        as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:20:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:30:00"),as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:07:00"),
                                                                                        as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:29:00")), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),tzone = "America/New_York"), 
               Leave.Time = structure(c(as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:25:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:22:00"), 
                                        as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 14:01:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 13:29:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-12-09 14:33:00")), 
                                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")),.Names = c("Email", "Join.Time", "Leave.Time"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"))

# creating a second dataframe to assign unique IDs (integer-valued)
Email <- unique(df$Email) # unique emails for ID
IDs <- 1:length(Email) # making ID number
df2 <- data.frame(Email,IDs) # creating df of IDs and emails
df_joined <- merge(df, df2) # joining values to create the IDs column

# setting margins, left margin wide to plot email as text
par(mar=c(4,6,4,1))

# initial plot layout
# could use limits of min and max times as limits or set your own
plot(x=NA,
     ,y=NA
     #xlim=c(min(df_joined$Join.Time),max(df_joined$Leave.Time)) # min and max used
     ,xlim=as.POSIXct(c("2020-12-09 13:00:00 EST","2020-12-09 14:45:00 EST")) # set your own
     ,ylim=c(1,length(Email)) # range of y axis
     ,xlab='Time' # x label
     ,ylab='' # y label not used
     ,main='User Participation' # title
     ,yaxt='n' # no y axis
     ,xaxt='n' # no x axis
     ,bty='n' # no box
     )

# adding x axis
# use min and max times or set your own
axis.POSIXct(side=1,
             x=c("2020-12-09 13:00:00 EST","2020-12-09 14:45:00 EST") # set your own
             #x = c(min(df_joined$Join.Time),max(df_joined$Leave.Time)) # min and max
             )

# loop over the unique IDs
for(i in 1:nrow(df_joined)){
    # creating a line for the ID
    lines(x=c(df_joined$Join.Time[i],df_joined$Leave.Time[i])
         ,y=rep(df_joined$IDs[i],2) # plotted at the unique ID integer value
         ,lwd=2 # line width
         ,col='gray' # line color
         )
}

# adding email address label for the line
par(xpd=T) # plot stuff outside axis limits
for(i in nrow(df2)){
  text(x=as.POSIXct(c("2020-12-09 13:00:00 EST")) # specified x location
       ,y=df2$IDs # y value is the ID used above
       ,labels=df2$Email # text
       ,adj=1.1
       ,cex=0.5)
}
par(xpd=F)
```